# Accidently deleted chrome inside /opt

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome, delete

I accidentally deleted chrome inside the `/opt` folder and now I get "Invalid desktop entry file" error while trying to launch it.

`sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable` displays I already have the newest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-install Chrome by running:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall google-chrome-stable
```